# Formatting chapter style in REPORT document class

Tags: sectioning, chapters

---

I am trying to write my Thesis using LaTeX. I am using the `report` document class. I have created multiple TeX files (one each for abstract, acknowledgment, and chapters) using 'chapters'. When I use the `titlesec` package to format the chapter heading it applies to the whole document changing even the table of content, list of figures and list of tables.

I want to keep the default chapter heading style for `frontmatter` and use a custom chapter style for the `mainmatter`

**Is there a way to apply different chapter style (default/multiple custom styles) to different chapters in the same document? Something similar to `pagestyle`!**

---

Comment: It is certainly possible to redefine chapter later in the document. But imho you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Can you show the code you have for redefining the chapter style?

Answer (score 0):

My thesis main tex looks sth like this:

```
... 
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{alph}
\input{caratula}
\newpage

\include{abstract}
\include{agradecimientos}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\clearpage

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%redefining plain pagestyle
...
}

\newpage
\include{capitulo_introduccion}
\include{capitulo_tdd}
\include{capitulo_atdd}
\include{capitulo_cambios}
\include{capitulo_propuesta_tesis}
\include{capitulo_casos_de_estudio}
\include{capitulo_trabajos_relacionados}
\include{capitulo_conclusiones}
...
\end{document}
```

There's a style for the table of contents and then I change it for the chapters (and then I change it again for the appendix).